# Appcelerator. Timestamp for property files

Tags: appcelerator-mobile

Titanium SDK version: 1.7.0
iPhone SDK version: 4.2

I am creating an iOS app and I am using property files as cache.
How can I get the created time (timestamp) for a property?

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 5):

I do something similar in my apps. I use a timestamp for syncing data with a backend server so I wrote a nitty-gritty function for easy access:

```
var timestamp = function(){
    return Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
};
```

Then

```
Ti.App.Properties.setString('timestamp', timestamp());
```

so what I do is return the current time as a timestamp and devide by 1000, this returns a UNIX timestamp, keeping things consistent with my backend system.

Adding it to a function means it's reusable, otherwise assigning it to a variable will do the same thing but the value will always be the same as what it was when initializing the app.

Answer (score 0):

At the same time that the property is created, I would just create a sister property with a timestamp string.

For example:

```
Titanium.App.Properties.setString("foo","bar");
var timeStamp = String(new Date().getTime());
Titanium.App.Properties.setString("foo_stamp",timeStamp);
```

As far as I know, the Property object has no properties, and only one value per key. I would probably create an anonymous function if you intend to do this more than a few times.

Comment: A possible problem with using a var is it will be locked to that value for as long as the app is running. So once the app starts the timestamp would be set to "1318462684000" until the app is fully closed and restarted, making any change to to the timestamp value impossible as long as the app is running.